# Differential privacy of "randomized responses"

Tags: differential-privacy

We define randomized responses as follows:

> In a question that can be responded with a "Yes" or "No", a respondent is asked to flip a fair coin, in secret, and answer the truth if it comes up tails. Otherwise he/she flips another coin in secret, and answers "Yes" if comes up tails, "No" otherwise.

According to the introduction this paper [1], the $\epsilon$-differential privacy of surveys relying on randomized responses is:
$$
\ln(0.75/(1-0.75)) = \ln(3)
$$
I am wondering how was this calculated. Note that the proofs contained in paper are related to the RAPPOR protocol.

[1]Úlfar Erlingsson, Vasyl Pihur, Aleksandra Korolova,"RAPPOR: Randomized Aggregatable Privacy-Preserving Ordinal Response"  https://research.google.com/pubs/archive/42852.pdf

Comment: There is a full proof in the paper, so you need to be more specific.

Comment: The proofs contained in paper are related to the RAPPOR protocol. What I am asking is how the differential privacy of the "randomized responses" was calculated. I have edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in this book  https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~aaroth/Papers/privacybook.pdf at page 30

> Fix a respondent. A case analysis shows that 
>   $$Pr[Response = Yes|Truth = Yes] = 3/4$$ 
>   Specifically, when the truth is “Yes” the
>   outcome will be “Yes” if the first coin comes up tails (probability
>   1/2) or the first and second come up heads (probability 1/4),
>   while $$Pr[Response = Yes|Truth = No] = 1/4$$ (first comes up heads and
>   second comes up tails; probability 1/4). Applying similar reasoning to
>   the case of a “No” answer, we obtain:
>   $$
> \frac{Pr[Response = Yes|Truth = Yes]}{Pr[Response = Yes|Truth = No]}=
> \frac{3/4}{1/4}= \frac{Pr[Response = No|Truth = No]}{ Pr[Response = No|Truth = Yes]} = 3$$

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer =)